# Can Buddhist marry non Buddhist?

Tags: non-buddhism, marriage

I have relationship with non Buddhist, and we both thinking seriously about marriage. My family could not accept him because he is not Buddhist. But as I learned so far , Buddhism teach us to love and respect all religion. Can I  marry him?

Comment: Here may be helpful [What is Buddhist law of marriage ? Is there any?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13607/what-is-buddhist-law-of-marriage-is-there-any)

Comment: Or Maybe [Any authentic sutta from any tradition that gives guidance on what kind of partner to choose?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/any-authentic-sutta-from-any-tradition-that-gives-guidance-on-what-kind-of-partn)

Comment: I can understand family, I'd say you may have to ask him to be a Buddhist. Can speak about Dhamma. This was happened to me.  But since it, my belief been stronger that I should marry a Buddhist girl  who is practicing Buddhism as well that not happen in India that's why.

Comment: No question if you can, you can marry him but when it's matter of family you can ask him to be a Buddhist. That I would do. May this way we can spread Buddhism. Thank you so much. **"May Buddha bless you!'**

Answer (score 8):

What a Buddhist should do is:

- Lead a moral life which is beneficial to others and to oneself.
- Try to develop control over your mind rather than be a slave to it.
- Try to develop an understanding of the true nature of phenomena and reality (cause and effect) with relation to the psychological impact which cause misery and use this understanding as a leverage to come out of misery.

So this question boils down to if a physiologist can marry a surgeon or engineer or some one who subscribes to a non-scientific dogma. **There is no issue.**

But again marriage comes with other responsibilities and issues afterwards. You have to think through how you can handle these before hand. Also evaluate the impact it might have on your personal development and meditation, and see if there are any personal "costs" involved, but again this is up to you.

Comment: I wonder if you're right about 'non-scientific dogma'. I suspect it would be a bad move to marry someone who subscribes to a dogma. It's a mind-set that will grate with a Buddhist and might easily become a problem. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There are no restrictions in marrying people of other belief systems.

Answer (score 1):

Can a non-Buddhist marry a Buddhist? In the eyes of a non-Buddhist, yes or no, or maybe.

Can a Buddhist marry a non-Buddhist or would he / she refrain from marrying a non-Buddhist?

He / she would leave the decision to the non-Buddhist.

The end decision to him / her would be the same - sun rises from the east, settles at the west. Water flows, birds sing, etc.

All the same. Remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Marriage demands mutual understanding not only between the marrying couple but between the two families. One of the most important thing you should consider before marrying a non Buddhist is if you would be able to continue your practice even after marriage. If you and your future husband are going to live by yourself without his family, then atleast he should know about your practice. If you are going to live with his family then its better that the whole family knows about your practice and that you would like to continue it. The story of Vishakha - chief laywoman disciple of Buddha would likely provide inspiration and guidance.

http://obo.genaud.net/backmatter/appendixes/personalities/visakha_migaramata.htm